# Activiti with kafka backbone

Tags: java, apache-kafka, activiti

[image]

Is it possible to use activiti as workflow front-end which uses kafka (or similar event queue) as processing pipeline.

Figure 1: normal activiti flow. The default activiti engine processes the flow through "java method calls"

Figure 2: same workflow but uses kafka event queue to invoke the tasks/processes

Is this possible? If yes, how?

Answer (score 2):

this is exactly what we are doing in Activiti Cloud -> https://activiti.gitbooks.io/activiti-7-developers-guide/content/
It is definitely possible, but we are trying to make it easy for people to do it. Right now we are using the Spring Cloud Stream RabbitMQ binder but that can be easily replaced by the Kafka Binder with no code changes.

Take a look at the gitbook for more details and feel free to join us in our gitter channel if you want to have a chat about this topic: https://gitter.im/Activiti/Activiti7?utm_source=share-link&utm_medium=link&utm_campaign=share-link

Comment: Thank you for the response. I will try it out and reply.

Comment: zeebe is something close  to this?

Comment: @AshikaUmangaUmagiliya aha, exactly, if you are going cloud you better check zeebe.io